# How to generate admin token after enabling 2FA?

Tags: magento2, api

Since I enabled 2FactorAuthentication my admin token API isn't working anymore.

My request is:

**POST:** `{{magento_url}}V1/integration/admin/token`

**Body:**

```
{
    "username":"{{admin_user}}",
    "password":"{{admin_password}}"   
}
```

How could I still using the REST API to generate my admin token by using 2FA?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your endpoint and body content. Then you will be able to generate it normally.

**POST:** `{{magento_url}}V1/tfa/provider/google/authenticate`

**Body:**

```
{
    "username":"{{admin_user}}",
    "password":"{{admin_password}}",
    "otp": "443445"
}
```